# Class '\App\User' not found in Laravel when changing the namespace

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I am having this error when moving `User.php` to `Models/User.php`

> local.ERROR: Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Fatal error:
>   Class '\App\User' not found
>
> vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php:126

Answer (score 221, accepted):

Go to config/auth.php and change App\User:class to App\Models\User::class.

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\Models\User::class,
    ],
```

Also change the namespace of User.php model

```
namespace App\Models;
```

Comment: If you had the same problem like me and did everything as described and the error still occurs try to clear the config cache like this:

`php artisan config:cache`
`php artisan config:clear`

Comment: no one was pointing at the namespace App\Models; in other answers

Comment: Thank you. I forgot to change User Model's namespace

Comment: I changed my project like your help, so it is not working for me. Can anyone help me plz.

Comment: add this command after changing your auth.php helped me much to remove the cache of previous configuration      rm bootstrap/cache/config.php

Answer (score 14):

If you are use the auth default on Laravel (`php artisan make:auth`), you have change the `RegisterController` on `app/Http/Controllers/Auth/`

```
use App\User;
```

to

```
use App\Models\User;
```

Also, for the rest of functionality, you have change the namespace on you User Model:

```
namespace App\Models;
```

And change  config/auth.php

```
'providers' => [
'users' => [
    'driver' => 'eloquent',
    'model' => App\Models\User::class,
],
```

Comment: Worked for me after updating App\Data\Models\User namespace..thanks

Answer (score 7):

These answers aren't right, you don't need to change the namespace to \App\Models\User.  The autoload will load the models folder but the class can still be `class User` and the namespace should still be `App`.  Is that how it is set up in your file?

```
namespace App;

class User extends Model {}
```

Answer (score 5):

Reload composer autloaded classes.

```
composer dump-autoload
```

Answer (score 4):

I was using Laravel 8x and found a simple idea using at the top of the <your_controller>.php

```
use App\Models\User
```

Comment: While this piece of code may provide a solution to the question, it's better to add context as to why/how it works. This can help future users refer to and eventually apply this knowledge to their own code. You are also likely to have positive feedback/upvotes from users, when the code is explained.

Comment: Please change the models spelling.

Answer (score 3):

if you are using user.php model file into folder Models/user.php
then  you need to change in follwing file so You will not get any Error

where to change if we create Model Folder in App\http ??

changer in folowing path ---

1      Config -
       - auth.php
       - search for users key change ---> app\user TO app\Models\user

2      venedor/composer/
        -autoload_classmap.php ----> BAse path (app\user TO app\Models\user)
        -autoload_static.php   ----> BAse path (app\user TO app\Models\user)

Answer (score 2):

I finally was able to resolve it by changing this the following code.

```
 array (
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => 'App\\Models\User',
      ),
```

Comment: where? in what file?

Comment: In config/auth.php file

Comment: manshu can you explain?

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RRm8QoW-hP4

Answer (score 2):

If the app config is cached, it may not be able to get the new configuration, because config:cache gives this error before clearing and caching configuration, so just delete the cache manually:

```
rm bootstrap/cache/config.php
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to change App\User to App\Models\User in config/auth.php

Answer (score 1):

What solved it for me was to change:

```
            'model' => '{YourAppName}\User',
```

Answer (score 1):

What happened is that you changed the location of the file user.php.

Your system is still looking for the file user.php in the old location. You need to give the system the right road to the file.

I gess you have to change the the code from 'model' => App\User::class, to

'model' => App\Models\User::class,

Answer (score 1):

I fixed the problem changing the `use App\User;` to `use MyAppName\User;`

Answer (score 1):

This problem is one of the `config` and `cache` settings, and by executing the following commands in the terminal, 90% of the problem will be fixed

```
config:clear
cache:clear
config:cache
```

Comment: Wow! genius. None of the other answers worked for me except this one. However, you need to edit your answer to include the prefix `php artisan` in the commands, otherwise, the commands would not be recognized. So, the correct commands would be `php artisan config:clear`, `php artisan cache:clear`, and `php artisan config:cache`. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I have got the same kind of issue a few days back. So I did this: Run this command

```
php artisan config:cache 
php artisan config:clear
```

And it solved my issue.Most of the issues are solved by this.
I recommend to try this first and if this doesn't solve your issue then go for other hacks.

Answer (score 0):

Check if your importations represent the exact name of your class. I found in one of my controllers I was imported `App\user` with "u" on lowercase instead of `App\User` with 'u' in uppercase

Answer (score 0):

i just change **use app\User** to **use App\User** and it works

Comment: Can you explain your answer further? How and why does it work?

Comment: its depends on server if your server is Linux then case sensitive if your server is windows then it ignore either App capitalize or small letters

Answer (score 0):

I had the same error. Everything on my config/auth.php and user.php was fine. So, I run MySQL server with Xampp and that solved the error. So, if you have a similar error You can try running MySql.

In my case, I was testing my routes with a Laravel app on Postman.

Answer (score 0):

I have faced same issue and get rid from it by matching the name (App\Models\User)in homecontroller and config->auth.php file ('model' => App\Models\User::class,).  **App\Models\User** is not same in my case Modal in auth file is first letter capitalize and in controller modal is in small letters. **Please match the upper & lowercase letters also**