# Laravel 5.4 throughs error class app user model not found

Tags: laravel-5

In auth.php

```
providers' => [
        'users' => [
            'driver' => 'eloquent',
            'model' => App\Models\User::class,
        ],
```

and in models/user.php

```
  namespace App\Models;
```

but message still

> Class '\App\Models\User' not found

Comment: did you change directory structure? default is ```'model' => App\User::class,``` and ```use App\User;```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821477/class-app-user-not-found-in-laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hmmm yes you should change `use App\Models;` to `namespace App\Models;`

and `use App\Models\User;`

Comment: @VeeZPhone are you sure about cache? try ```php artisan config:cache``` and check it again

Comment: add ```use App\Models\User;``` and test it