# [PHP][LARAVEL] "Class 'App\User' not found" but there is clearly 'use App\User;' in the code

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using some very simple code in "api.php" in Laravel and this error is driving me nuts.

Code:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\User;

// list new user
Route::get('users', function() {
    // If the Content-Type and Accept headers are set to 'application/json', 
    // this will return a JSON structure. This will be cleaned up later.
    return User::all();
});

// create new user
Route::post('users/add', function(Request $request) {
    return User::create($request->all);
});
```

Error:

> Class 'App\User' not found

How is this even possible?

Comment: Have you created an `User` class in the `App` namespace?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Class '\App\User' not found in Laravel when changing the namespace](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821477/class-app-user-not-found-in-laravel-when-changing-the-namespace)

Comment: If you're using the standard boilerplate Laravel install then this will not happen so it might be useful to share any code that we can use to reproduce this issue.

Comment: try changing `App\User` to `\App\User`

Answer (score 2):

Hi can you please verify that the namespace on top of User.php model is namespace App;?

Something like:

```
<?php
namespace App;

use Illuminate\Notifications\Notifiable;`
use Illuminate\Notifications\MustVerifyEmail;
```

Answer (score 0):

check the namespace in model `User.php`.It should be `App\User`

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you run `composer update`, then `composer dumpautoload`

Answer (score 0):

Try to refresh existing composer files:

```bash
composer dump-autoload
```

Also, check your "autoload" section in composer.json.