# Class &#039;App/User&#039; not found in file .... WebhookController.php on line 208 Laravel Cashier Stripe Webhook

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-cashier

Here is the portion of my Webhook Controller where it says the error is. Everything looks correct to me. What might I be missing?

Also, only the handle payment invoice webhook works, everything else gives me the 500 error below.

```
  /**
 * Get the billable entity instance by Stripe ID.
 *
 * @param  string|null  $stripeId
 * @return \Laravel\Cashier\Billable|null
 */
protected function getUserByStripeId($stripeId)
{
    if ($stripeId === null) {
        return;
    }

    $model = config('cashier.model');

    return (new $model)->where('stripe_id', $stripeId)->first();

}
```

Here is the 500 error I get when I try to test the stripe Webhook.

```
Test webhook error: 500

Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError: Class &#039;App/User&#039; not found in file /.../vendor/laravel/cashier/src/Http/Controllers/StripeWebhookController.php on line 208
```

My user file is in App\User. Her is my User file

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{

use Notifiable, Billable;


protected $connection = 'mongodb';


/**
 * The attributes that are mass assignable.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $fillable = [
    'name', 'email', 'username', 'password', 'phone',
];
/**
* The collection name
*
* @var array
*/
protected $collection = 'users';

/**
* The attributes that are mass assignable.
*
* @var array
*/
protected $dates = ['deleted_at'];
/**
 * The attributes that should be hidden for arrays.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $hidden = [
    'password', 'remember_token',
];

/**
 * The attributes that should be cast to native types.
 *
 * @var array
 */
protected $casts = [
    'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
];

}
```

Here is my config\auth.php

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

Comment: This sounds like a Laravel error: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821477/class-app-user-not-found-in-laravel-when-changing-the-namespace

Comment: Please check do you have the code 'use App\User' under the namespace and on the top.

Comment: what is the namespace of your User model, have you imported your User model to this class? answer to this two questions should solve your problem.

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu The namespace of my User model is, namespace App; how do I import User model to this class? Thanks

Comment: @rohit I have 'use App\User;' under the namespace. Thanks.

Comment: In that case you should be importing it as’use App\User;’

Comment: @PrafullaKumarSahu Yes, 'use App\User;' is listed below the namespace in my Webhook Controller. Are you saying it should also be in my User model under the namespace there? Thanks

Comment: @floatingLomas unfortunately I did not find a solution in that thread. Thanks.

Comment: @Laing, if you know tinker, you can try if you are able to use your model with same namespace, or you can even try it on your route files, if you are getting same error, you may need to regenerate your autoload file, use `php artisan dump-autoload`, that should help you.

Answer (score 1):

Please check your config/auth.php file and look for this code

```
'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],
```

Check whether your model is located in app folder or in app\Models? If it is in model folder, then change `App\User` with `App\Models\User`.

If it does not work, pplease try to clear the cache using these commands:

```
php artisan config:cache
php artisan config:clear
```

Comment: my config/auth.php is correctly configured, the App\User is in the correct place. Also I ran 'php artisan config:cache' and
'php artisan config:clear' commands, unfortunately I am still receiving the error. Thanks.