# Moving laravel db models into folder Models (App\Models) as per Laravel 8 gives error

Tags: laravel, model

I though I was clever to organise all the DB models into the folder as per Laravel 8 which I am running on my project...

What I did is :

1. create the folder and move all the models into so now i.e. Articles.php is inside the app/Models folder
2. add "namespace App\models;" in each model file
3. replace all the instance of "use App\Article;" by "use App\Models\Article;" in all controllers

Now I get an error "Class '\App\User' not found (View: ...list.blade.php) which is displayed through the controller where all the models are properly defined as above.

If I run artisan dumpautoload I get "Class App\models\Article located in ./app/Models/Article.php does not comply with psr-4 autoloading standard. Skipping."

So what do I have to do to fix that issue?

Comment: @ZiaYamin  There is no use of model files there.

Comment: `namespace App\models` to `namespace App\Models` `m` to `M`

Comment: The folder is Models and all the namspaces App\Models I checked that @KamleshPaul  but I see that the dumpautoload error is "Class App\models\Article located in ./app/Models/Article.php" where does "models" with lowercase come from?  Should I rename everything with lowercase?

Comment: I am so sorry only the Article model had a namespace with lowercase... thank you @KamleshPaul

Comment: if your problem not solved, check here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35821477/class-app-user-not-found-in-laravel-when-changing-the-namespace

Comment: Indeed there was still one issue... and that post fixed it. Thank you a million @KamleshPaul

Answer (score 2):

Make sure the namespace you use is capitalized correctly - namespace App/Models rather than the App/models you noted above.

You may also need to update the file config/auth.php. Find the 'User Providers' section and look for the 'model' entry which points to the User model.

Comment: But there is still an error "vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Auth/EloquentUserProvider.php:183"  ... "Class '\App\User' not found (View: /.../resources/views/dashboard/list.blade.php) and there is no use of User in that file.

Comment: What is the full error message?